# How can I Do this without Download any software

Tags: photo-editing

I have some jpeg files, which contains text. I want to edit some information on it.

How can I do this without downloading any software?

Comment: Which Operating System are you using?

Comment: Also, how is the text embedded in the files?

Comment: @Mechanical, the text is just rasterized into the picture. There’s probably a watermark or something (like how many wallpapers have the URL of the site in the corner) on the picture and they want to either remove it or change the text.

Comment: @Synetech inc.:  Good call (+1) -- I was thinking of meta-data such as the model of the camera used to take the picture and other such data that sometimes gets stored outside of the scope of what's visible.

Comment: @Synetech inc.: then it's an OCR question?

Comment: @Mechanical, partly, it’s also partly a raster-graphics-editing question.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you're using Windows your only real solution is [Paint](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paint_%28software%29), which comes with your standard Windows install. Depending on the source image this could look anything from adequate to horrible.

A little more information about your situation could help, like what you mean by edit info on it (e.g. are we talking the meta data of the image or the actual content, I have assumed actual content.)

Comment: @user60065, you may not be able to *download* software, but can you *install* some, say from a CD or flash-drive? If not, you’re really tying your hands because MSPaint is indeed the *only* graphics program that comes with Windows. So if you can’t use *any* third-party software, then that’s all you’ll be able to use; in which case good luck! (Oh and, *conversion* is the wrong tag; *photo-editing* would be closer.)

Answer (score 0):

first, you did not tell us about your OS. Second, we do not know, how the text is embedded. If you do not have PSD or XCF files, which can contain separate and well editable text layers (you will need free GIMP or payed Photoshop to edit it) and you have only jpegs/gifs or pngs, then it is more complicated.

If I imagine a photograph overlayed with text and I want to edit the text, I have only few possibilities:

1) use MS Paint in Windows or for example GIMP (contained in many linux distros), delete the text area and put other text there (you will have to write it again) - the output will not be very nice :-(

2) use some online OCR like:
http://www.onlineocr.net/
or 
http://www.free-ocr.com/
to extract the text from image and then work similarly to 1) but use recognized text from OCR instead of writing it from scratch.